# Positive Definite Quadratic Forms Equivalent Condition

Tags: quadratic-forms, positive-definite

The condition of a matrix $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to be positive definite is that $x^TQx>0$ for all $x\neq 0$.

I would like to know if the following is an equivalent condition: $x^TQx>0$ for all $0\neq x\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $Q$ is invertible.

It is necessary to include the condition that $Q$ is invertible since $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\pi \\ -\pi & \pi^2 \end{bmatrix}$ is a $2$-dimensional example of a matrix that has $x^TQx>0$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ but is clearly not positive definite in the real sense.

Does somebody know of a conterexample that shows that my "equivalent" does not hold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the condition $x^TQx > 0$ for all non-zero $x \in \Bbb Z^n$ is sufficient.

On proof is as follows. Consider an arbitrary $x \in \Bbb R^n$.  Let $x_k$ be a sequence in $\Bbb Q^n$ with $x_k \to x$.  For any $x_k$, there exists an intger $N>0$ such that $Nx_k \in \Bbb Z^n$ (for instance, take $N$ to be the least common denominator among all entries of $x$). With that, we have
$$
(Nx_k)^TQ(Nx_k) > 0 \implies x_k^TQx_k = \frac{(Nx_k)^TQ(Nx_k)}{N^2} > 0.
$$
So, $x_k^TQx_k \geq 0$ for all $k$, and by the continuity of $x \mapsto x^TQx$ we have $x_k^TQx_k \to x^TQx$.  It follows that $x^TQx \geq 0$.

Because $Q$ is invertible and $x^TQx \geq 0$ for all $x$, we can conclude that $Q$ is positive definite, as was desired.

Comment: Yes, I got this far. It was the last step I was stuck on, but if I'm correct we can use diagonlization to show that $Q$ is positive definite (since we may assume that it is symmetric).

Comment: @Cellardoor I don't understand what you're getting stuck on here

Comment: How is it immediatly clear that $Q$ is invertible and $x^TQx\geq 0$ implies $Q$ positive definite? (I understand that we can use diagonalization).

Comment: @Cellardoor I understand now.  We are given that $Q$ is symmetric.  If $Q$ is positive semidefinite, then its eigenvalues are non-negative.  If $Q$ is invertible, then its eigenvalues are non-zero.  So, $Q$ is invertible and positive semidefinite implies that $Q$ is symmetric with positive eigenvalues and therefore positive definite.

Comment: @Cellardoor an alternative proof.  Suppose that $Q$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite, and invertible.  Let $Q = LL^T$ be a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).  Because $Q$ is invertible, $L$ is invertible.  So, if $x$ is a non-zero vector, then
$$
x^TQx = x^TLL^Tx = (L^Tx)^T(L^Tx) = \|L^Tx\|^2
$$
must be non-zero.  So $Q$ is positive definite.

Comment: I also thought about doing something like that, however I believe we must assume that $Q$ is positive-definite to even know that a Cholesky decompsition exists. It says so on your link.

Comment: @Cellardoor as is clarified [on this part of the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices), Cholesky decompositions also exist for positive semidefinite matrices

Comment: Interesting, thank you.